# Carousel layout doesn't render in Botframework .

Tags: botframework

I'm working on creating a card with carousel layout using more than 5 hero cards but it doesn't render on Skype. When I tried with 5 cards, the carousel card was rendered very well.

Is there a limitation on number of cards in carousel layout?

Also I added a text in the response but it isn't shown on top of the carousel. Is there an issue in rendering the text with carousel card?

This is the JSON representaiton of the card:

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "attachmentLayout": "carousel",
  "text": "test carousel card",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "https://catcafemelbourne.com/wp-content/uploads/IMG_4535.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "buttons": []
      }
    },
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "http://www.wildcatconservation.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/2016-sand-cat-group.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "buttons": []
      }
    },
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/700px-394px/cats-noses-wet_756a0c5cb206e0c3.jpg?domain=cx.aos.ask.com"
          }
        ],
        "buttons": []
      }
    },
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "http://www.staustell.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/homepage_banner/BranchBannerPlaceholder.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "buttons": []
      }
    },
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "http://www.aspca.org/sites/default/files/cat-care_urine-marking_main-image.jpg"
          }
        ],
        "buttons": []
      }
    },
    {
      "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
      "content": {
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/02/01-13-things-you-didnt-know-about-cats-earthquakes.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "replyToId": "628713ea564044c8a27edc689750515f"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype currently limits the number of carousel cards to 5.

Comment: Is there any reference/document for that?

The text in the carousel card isn't shown, is this an issue in rendering the text with the carousel card?

Comment: It does appear to be missing from the documentation.  When you say the text in the carousel card isn't shown, are you referring to a different issue that you are seeing?